# Cannot access magento admin panel?

Tags: magento

When I try to access admin panel on magento , It returns this error :

```
There has been an error processing your request

Mage registry key "_resource_helper/core" already exists

Trace:
#0 /home6/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home6/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php(563): Mage::register('_resource_helpe...', false)
#2 /home6/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(534): Mage::getResourceHelper('core')
#3 /home6/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_prepareSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#4 /home6/domain/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#5 /home6/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Website/Collection.php(137): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load(false, false)
#6 /home6/domain/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(729): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website_Collection->load()
#7 /home6/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(634): Varien_Data_Collection->getItemById('0')
#8 /home6/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#9 /home6/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#10 /home6/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home6/domain/public_html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

What's the problem ? It hasn't any problem before , I just saw this error suddenly this morning . 
And Also , I've tried these ssh shell commands :

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*
```

And even I've deleted these folders contents by cpanel . But still it gives that error .
How can I fix it ?

Comment: check `local.xml` file. It should have `<model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>` set

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to your phpmyadmin

search the DB for this key

then remove the key or rename the value.

Comment: I've tried searching at phpmyadmin , but there was 0 result for searching .